# fgets inside of a For loop causing strange behavior

Tags: c, fgets

I'm trying to get user input using fgets and some funky (not correct) things are happening and I can't seem to understand why.

The program is run with an argument that indicates how many values the user is to input.

Here is how the program is supposed to run:

```
./a.out 6
Enter 6 integer values to place in tree:
5
4
3
2
1
6
Input values:
5
4  
3
2
1
6
```

If I have 1 as the argument, it doesn't even allow me to enter an input, and where did the 0 come from?

```
./a.out 1
Enter 1 integer values to place in tree:
Input values:
0
```

If I have 2 as the argument, it only allows me to enter 1 input and the phantom 0 appears again.

```
./a.out 2
Enter 2 integer values to place in tree:
1
Input values: 
1
0
```

If I have 3 or more arguments, it functions correctly.

Here's the source:

```
int main (int argc, const char* argv[]){
   int numIntegers;
   char buffer[20];
   if (argc == 1){
      printf("Usage: a.out #\n");
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
   }
   else{
      numIntegers = atoi(argv[1]);
      if (numIntegers <= 0){
         printf("# must be greater than 0\n");
         return EXIT_FAILURE; 
      }
      else{
         int intArray[numIntegers];
         printf("Enter %d integer values to place in tree: \n", numIntegers);
         for (int i = 0; i < numIntegers; i++){
            fgets(buffer, numIntegers, stdin);
            intArray[i] = atoi(buffer);
         }
         printf("Input values:\n");
         for (int i = 0; i < numIntegers; i++){
            printf(%d\n", intArray[i]);
         }
      }
   }
}//end main
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *size* argument to `fgets()` refers to the size of `buffer`, which should be 20 in your case.

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

---

By the way, your code won't actually compile.

```
printf(%d\n", intArray[i]);    // missing a quotation mark
```

Comment: Thank you chris, that solved it! It's always the little things.